# pr-str also prints out trace messages

Tags: clojure

I am using `pr-str` to print EDN to string and communicate with the client side. Encountered very interesting behavior where `pr-str` also outputs `println` or `clojure.tools.trace/trace` messages mixed into the EDN string representation. This is the kind of strings `pr-str` outputs:

```
(TRACE from-ds {:key "asdasf", :weight 0, :tag "1"} ; trace message

{:key "asdasf", :weight 0, :tag "1"}) ; the actual edn that should be the sole output
```

I can't seem to reproduce this in REPL.

Why is this happening? How to work around it?

Comment: `println` [has a race condition](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2014-12-11-14-race-condition-in-clojure-println.html)?

Comment: `print` (and by extension `println`) has no coordination to prevent overlappint output, but the result you get here could only happen if the code inside your `pr-str` call is creating output. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pr-str` uses `with-out-str`, which captures any print output that happens while inside its block and turns it into a string which is returned.

`with-out-str` creates a thread-local binding of `*out*`. Because of this, the only way that you could be getting log output inside your output string is if the code inside your `pr-str` call was logging. This could be fixed by binding the value outside `pr-str` call and then calling `pr-str` on that value.

eg.

```
(let [the-value (generate-some-value) ; this prints something
      value-string (pr-str the-value)] ; this doesn't have trace output
  ...)
```